# Graalvm native-image for a scala app: No configuration setting found for key 'myapp'

Tags: scala, graalvm

I am building a native image for a Scala app that uses SimpleConfig.

When I run the native image, I get this error message:

```
> ./myapp
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: system properties: No configuration setting found for key 'eqwalizer'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:157)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:175)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:194)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:269)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:275)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:42)
    at com.myapp.package$.config$lzycompute(package.scala:20)
    at com.myapp.package$.config(package.scala:19)
    at com.myapp.Main$.main(Main.scala:15)
    at com.myapp.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Is there something I have to do to embed a config file in the native image?

I do not know very much about JVM stuff and no idea what aspects of this problem are to do with sbt vs. jvm vs. graalvm vs. properties files etc.

I get this error regardless of how I build the native image:

- using the [`native-image` executable directly](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#native-images)
- using the [sbt-native-image plugin](https://github.com/scalameta/sbt-native-image)

Answer (score 4):

include the resource using this command line flag:

`-H:IncludeResources='application.conf'`

The flag accepts a java regex

Comment: Did you have to specify the full path i.e. `resources/application.conf`?

Comment: I don't think so, but this was a long time ago and I'm not sure if I remember